# Type does not have a default constructor automapper

Tags: automapper

I have a problem:

```
public class TDocumentation
{
   public XmlElement Summary { get; set; }

   public XmlElement LongDescription { get; set; }

   public XmlAttribute[] AnyAttr { get; set; }
}
```

...and:

```
public class ProxieTDocumentation
{
    public XmlElement Summary { get; set; }

    ......
}


Mapper.CreateMap<Proxies.TDocumentation, TDocumentation>()
```

...throws:

----> System.ArgumentException : Type "System.Xml.XmlElement" does not have a default     constructor automapper

How I can make a mapping on another?

Comment: What version of Automapper?  I just tried this with 2.0 and I didn't get the exception (using the class definitions you posted).

Comment: thanks for the answer, i use version 2.1.265.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve thie promleb:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<XmlElement, XmlElement>().ConvertUsing(item => item != null ? item.Clone() as XmlElement : null);
```